# Тг бот отключается через 2-3 дня на Pythonanywhere

Tags: python, aiogram, pythonanywhere

Я запускаю бота через кнопку "Run", бот начинает работать в фоновом режиме, но через 2-3 дня он перестает работу, что мне сделать чтобы бот работал безпрерывно или хотябы прослужил дольше. Бот написан на библиотеке "Aiogramm"

Comment: купить vps для бота или оплатить там же соответствующий тариф

Answer (score 0):

Телеграм-боты имеют два способа взаимодействия с серверами Телеграма: [поллинг и вебхуки](https://grammy.dev/guide/deployment-types).

На личном опыте выяснил, что поллинг имеет свойство часто отваливаться, в отличие от неубиваемых вебхуков.

Из минусов вебхуков:

- Тебе нужен не только белый IP, но и домен
- Нужен SSL-сертификат, дабы принимать запросы от Телеграма по https (иначе он не разрешит))

Comment: Нууу или всегда можно запихать всё в докер и поставить `restart: on-failure`

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогла вот такая конструкция (бот может стопорится даже на VPS).
Возможно и вам поможет:

```
while True:
    try:
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            asyncio.run(main())
    except Exception as e:
        time.sleep(3)
        print(e)
```